# Multiplying elements of two lists in all possible orders

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists:

```
U1 = {u10, u11, u12};
U2 = {u20,u21, u22};
```

and I want to get a third list that will be the product of these two lists in a particular order. the third list will look like this:

```
UU = {u10, u20, u10 * u11, u10 * u21, u11 * u20, u20 * u21,
      u10 * u11 * u12, u10 * u11 * u22, u10 * u12 * u21,
      u10 * u21 * u22, u11 * u12 * u20, u11 * u20 * u22,
      u12 * u20 * u21, u20 * u21 * u22}
```

so if I take these lists in terms of actual numbers, as,

```
U1 = {2, 3, 4};
U2 = {1, 2, 3};
```

I should get,

```
UU = {2, 1, 6, 4, 3, 2, 24, 18, 16, 12, 12, 9, 8, 6}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

the pattern can be observed using NCExpand.

I was getting it using:

```
UU = MonomialList[NCExpand[(u11 + u21) ** (u20 + u10)]]
```

giving me

```
(* {u10 u11, u10 u21, u11 u20, u20 u21} *)
```

and when used again

```
UU = MonomialList[NCExpand[(u12 + u22) ** (u11 + u21) ** (u10 + u20)]]
```

results in

```
(* {u10 u11 u12, u10 u11 u22, u10 u12 u21, u10 u21 u22, u11 u12 u20, u11 u20 u22, u12 u20 u21, u20 u21 u22} *)
```

the problem is, I want to get the product list as one list and in general way like if I just define my `U1` and `U2` and generally get my `UU`.

Comment: I think it would here to explain what the pattern/math actually is.  Including an example is great, but I can't discern from the example what the actual *structure* is, and so I can't figure out how to automate it.  Can you update your post to include information about the logic behind the pattern?

Comment: sure, this kind of pattern could be observed using NCExpand. let me share It in my post.

Comment: I still don't understand this pattern, but FWIW `UU` is definitely a subset of 
`MapApply[Times, Subsets[all, {1, 3}]]`. 

$$ $$
`allProducts =MapApply[Times, Subsets[all, {1, 3}]];`
`Sort@Intersection[UU, allProducts] === Sort@UU`
`(*True*)`

I am still struggling to see what property links all the elements in UU together though. There has to be some way to select the right products from `allProducts` if they share some kind of property.

Comment: but in this case I have to manually define UU. i want to get UU as a result of the multiplication.

Comment: When I define my U1 = {2, 3, 4}, and U2 = {1, 2, 3} and getting all products by using allProducts = Times @@ # & /@ Subsets[Join[U1, U2], {1, 3}] it is resulting in one list as {2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 2, 4, 6, 12, 3, 6, 9, 4, 8, 12, 2, 3, 6, 24, 6, 12, 18, 8, 16, 24, 4, 6, 12, 12, 24, 36, 6, 9, 18, 8, 12, 24, 6}

Comment: and even if I am defining my UU as **UU = {2, 1, 6, 4, 3, 2, 24, 18, 16, 12, 12, 9, 8, 6}** manually (in actual I want to get this list as a result) then sorting intersection according to your method as **Sort@Intersection[UU, allProducts] === Sort@UU** I am getting **False**

Comment: This is because `Intersection` only shows unique elements that occur in both lists, so if each list shares two 2s, it will only show one 2. I just used that with the symbolic U1 and U2 to show that what your looking for is a subset of all of the products between the two, but I'm still unsure what the criterion is for selecting the elements you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to bundle this into a function that you can use multiple times and then get your final result by aggregation.

```
IndexedBinaryChoice[listA_, listB_, slotCount_Integer] :=
  Map[
    Apply[Times]@*Flatten@*MapIndexed[Part[{listA, listB}, ##] &],
    Tuples[{1, 2}, slotCount]] /;
  Length[listA] == Length[listB]
```

I came up with this by interpreting your question as follows. The pattern seems to take 1, 2, and 3 "columns" of the matrix `{U1, U2}` in turn. It appears that we have 2 terms from the 1-column case, 4 terms from the 2-column case, and 8 terms from the 3 column case. Further inspection of your example suggests that for the n-column case we have a "template" list of indexes of length n, something like `{x[[1]], x[[2]], x[[3]]}` in the 3-column case, where we can then replace each `x` with either `U1` or `U2`. There are 2^n ways to choose the replacements, which matches our observation above.

So, at the heart we have `Tuples[{1, 2}, slotCount]`. The `1` and `2` represent our choices (choose from `U1` or from `U2`), and `slotCount` is how many columns we want to cover. A tuple like `{1, 2, 1}` means "in the first slot, choose from `U1`, in the second from `U2`, and in the third from `U1`. Of course, we want to generalize, so `U1` and `U2` really mean "the first and second inputs".

Now, I want to map a "chooser" over each tuple. The chooser will index into the input lists. If I bundle my inputs like `inputs = {first, second}`, then the tuple `{1, 2, 1}` means `{inputs[[1]][[1]], inputs[[2]][[2]], inputs[[1]][[3]]}`, which means I need to keep track of where in the tuple I am as I map the chooser over it. That suggests using `MapIndexed`: `MapIndexed[Part[{first, second}, ##] &][{1, 2, 1}]`. We need to compose this basic chooser function with `Times` since that's how you wanted to transform each tuple-choice, and we need to map this whole thing over all the tuples.

Testing it on the 1-slot case:

```
IndexedBinaryChoice[U1, U2, 1]
(* {u10, u20} *)
```

2-slot case:

```
IndexedBinaryChoice[U1, U2, 2]
(* {u10 u11, u10 u21, u11 u20, u20 u21} *)
```

3-slot case:

```
IndexedBinaryChoice[U1, U2, 3]
(* {u10 u11 u12, u10 u11 u22, u10 u12 u21, u10 u21 u22, u11 u12 u20, u11 u20 u22, u12 u20 u21, u20 u21 u22} *)
```

Now, let's just refine our definition of `IndexedBinaryChoice` by adding this:

```
IndexedBinaryChoice[listA_, listB_] :=
  Flatten[IndexedBinaryChoice[listA, listB, #] & /@ Range[Length@listA]] /; 
  Length[listA] == Length[listB]
```

And now,

```
IndexedBinaryChoice[U1, U2]
(* This should be equal to UU *)
```

You might want to add other validity checks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. your code is giving me the desired list of **UU={2, 1, 6, 4, 3, 2, 24, 18, 16, 12, 12, 9, 8, 6}**. Is it possible if you can explain the definition that you are providing for **IndexedBinaryChoice**.

Comment: Updated........

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

With

```
U1 = {u10, u11, u12};
U2 = {u20,u21, u22};
```

we do:

```
FoldList[Times, U1 + U2] // MonomialList // Flatten
```

if order doesn't matter and

```
Distribute /@ FoldList[NonCommutativeMultiply, U1 + U2] // MonomialList // Flatten
```

if order matters.

Finally, for lists of integers such as

```
U1 = {2, 3, 4};
U2 = {1, 2, 3};
```

we can do

```
indexedBinaryChoice2[U1_, U2_] := Module[
  {u, v, u1, u2, rules},
  u1 = Array[u, Length@U1]; u2 = Array[v, Length@U2];
  rules = Thread[Join[u1, u2] -> Join[U1, U2]];
  Flatten@MonomialList@FoldList[Times, u1 + u2] /. rules
 ]
```

or

```
Distribute[#, CirclePlus] & /@ FoldList[Times, Thread@CirclePlus[U1, U2]] /. CirclePlus -> Sequence
```

---

**Explanation**

Since these are just the monomials arising by multiplying elements of `U1 + U2`, we generate a list of the multiplications using

```
FoldList[Times, U1 + U2]
(* {u10 + u20, (u10 + u20) (u11 + u21), (u10 + u20) (u11 + u21) (u12 + u22)} *)
```

Then, we use `MonomialList`, which maps over lists, to extract the monomials in each term in each element of the list:

```
FoldList[Times, U1 + U2] // MonomialList
(* {{u10, u20},
    {u10 u11, u10 u21, u11 u20, u20 u21},
    {u10 u11 u12, u10 u11 u22, u10 u12 u21, u10 u21 u22, u11 u12 u20, u11 u20 u22, u12 u20 u21, u20 u21 u22}} *)
```

Since this is a list of lists, we just `Flatten` it at the end.

If order matters (which could be the case since OP is using `NCExpand`), do instead

```
Distribute /@ FoldList[NonCommutativeMultiply, U1 + U2] // MonomialList // Flatten
```

The only difference here is that we need to tell *Mathematica* that our version of `NonCommutativeMultiply` distributes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your understanding is correct and you are getting a correct pattern but because **FoldList** giving us the addition of elements so when I am using the **U1** and **U2** defined in terms of actual numbers (that is the goal) then I am not getting the desired **UU** instead I am getting the list **{3, 15, 105}**. to note, **U1 = {2,3,4}** and **U2= {1,2,3}** as defined previously.

Comment: @FatimaRAZA See the updated answer,

Comment: Yes, that is working. Thank you.